# After redirect to Paypal from site discount amount is not deducted

Tags: magento-1.9, paypal, discount, paypal-standard

I have discount on my site, and its apply correct on my Magento 1.9.0.1, but when we redirect to PayPal, its not deduct discount amount, its show all amount without discount. 
Please suggest some solution.